# jQuery to disable checkbox based off value of corresponding hidden field

Tags: jquery, loops, checkbox, hidden

I have 91 checkboxes and 91 corresponding hidden elements. I'm attempting to loop through the hidden elements and those which have a value of 0, disable the corresponding checkbox. The template variable will get replaced with either 0 or 1 before the page is served up.

Here is some of my markup:

```
    <input type="hidden" class="h_status" name="enabled_25" value="0">
<br><input type="checkbox" class="c_status" name="perm_25" value="1"> Create RPL Invoice

<input type="hidden" class="h_status" name="enabled_50" value="0">
<br><input type="checkbox" class="c_status" name="perm_50" value="1"> Uncancel Invoice 

<input type="hidden" class="h_status" name="enabled_49" value="0">
<br><input type="checkbox" class="c_status" name="perm_49" value="1"> Flag As Fraud

<input type="hidden" class="h_status" name="enabled_54" value="1">
<br><input type="checkbox" class="c_status" name="perm_54" value="1"> Change Initials

<input type="hidden" class="h_status" name="enabled_3" value="1">
<br><input type="checkbox" class="c_status" name="perm_3" value="1"> View/Edit CC Info

<input type="hidden" class="h_status" name="enabled_52" value="1">
<br><input type="checkbox" class="c_status" name="perm_52" value="1"> View Invoice History

<input type="hidden" class="h_status" name="enabled_47" value="1">
<br><input type="checkbox" class="c_status" name="perm_47" value="1"> Reprint Pull Copy
```

My initial attempt at the jQuery does not work (none of the checkboxes get disabled). I loop through the hidden elements using the each function and the h_status selector. Then, if the value of any element is blank or 0, disable the checkbox using the c_status selector.

Here's my code so far (please be gentle, I'm still learning):

```
$('.h_status').each(function(){

    var tempval = $(this).val();

    if ( tempval == "" || tempval == 0 ){       
        $('.c_status').prop('disabled', true);      
    }
});
```

Comment: use single quotes for your value =
how is the parser supposed to know if the " next to name= is a new start-quote or a closing quote for value="

Comment: <tmpl_var name=xyz> gets replaced with 0 or 1, so the page is served up with value="0" or value="1" for the hidden fields.

Comment: What's the result? The first checkbox is always disabled, but not anything else?

Comment: on a second look, your markup for the hidden checkboxes makes no sense (no offense, I get that you're learning). Why is <tmpl_var name="perm_47"> INSIDE of the input tag? its not even assigned to the value property. What is that supposed to be? a property? a value?

Comment: I changed the markup to minimize any confusion (I removed the template variables that get replaced with values by a perl script).

Comment: @Samurai, nothing is getting disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will work:

```
$('.h_status').each(function(){
    var d = $(this).val() == 0 ? false : true;
    var name = $(this).attr('name').split('_');
    $('input[name="perm_'+name[1]+'"]').prop('disabled', d);
});
```

Disclaimer: *untested*

Comment: I can follow your logic, but the console shows: TypeError: name is not a function

Comment: @VinnyTony Sorry there was a typo in my answer but it is fixed now. `name(1)` should be `name[1]`

Comment: I changed $(this).val() == 0 to $(this).val() != 0 and it works! I would vote this up but I need a better rep. :)

Comment: @VinnyTony Glad it works! Also, you can probably use `this.value` instead of `$(this).val()` and a basic `for` loop would be better that jquery's `.each`. Vanilla javascript will always perform better.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't contained any of the inputs/checkboxes together, and what I think you're trying to do is a 1 to 1 relationship, You'll have to use something like `.next()` to get the appropriate checkbox.

```
$('.h_status').each(function(){
    var thisInput = $(this).attr('name');
    var thisInputNum = thisInput.split("_")[1];
    var thisVal = $(this).val();
    if(!thisVal){
        $('.c_status[name="perm_' + thisVal + '"]').prop('disabled', true);  
    }
});
```